# How to print occurrences of letters and words in C (Pointers Encouraged)

Tags: c, string, pointers

I've gotten this far with my code with getting the letter occurrences. My strategy is to have the array index indicate what letter that index is storing the number of occurrences for. Ex: `'a'` = `65` `'b'` = `66` `'b'-'a'` = `1`, ( meaning `letters[1]` holds the occurrences for `'b'`).
I need help to print each letter and the number of occurrences since the index of the array is what expresses each letter, and they're numbers. I'm not even sure how I'm going to go about counting the occurrence of words based on their length (1,2,3, etc.. letter words). The hardest part would probably be outputting all the words in alphabetical order. I've completed the occurrences of letters portion of the code but I get this crazy error.

The specific instructions are in that photo:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/129493888@N03/17068676506/player/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int strLength;
    int *ptr_strLength;
    char textStream[];
    int cont = 1;
    while (cont != 0)
    {
        scanf("%s", textStream[]);
        strLength = strlen(textStream[]);
    }
    ptr_strLength = &strLength;
    void findLetters(ptr_strLength);
)

    void findLetters(int *ptr) //find occurences of all letters
    {
        int upLetters[26];
        int loLetters[26];
        char text[];
        int index;
        int a = 65;
        int lowA = 97;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int e = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int length;
        length = *ptr;

        while (textStream[i] != '\0')
        {
            for (; i < length ); i++)
            {
                if (isalpha(textStream[i])) //checks if char is an alphabet
                {
                    for (; a < 123); a++) 
                    {
                        if (textStream[i] = a)
                        {
                            if (textStream[i] > 64 && textStream[i] < 91) //stores occurrences of uppercase letters
                            {
                                textStream[i] - a = index;
                                upLetters[index] = upLetters[index] + textStream[i] - textStream[i] + 1;
                            }


                            if (textStream[i] > 89 && textStream[i] < 123) //stores occurrences of lowercase letters
                            {
                                textStream[i] - lowA = index;
                                loLetters[index] = loLetters[index] + textStream[i] - textStream[i] + 1;
                            }
                         }
                    }
                }

                printf("Number of Occurrences of letters\n\n");

                if(upLetters[0] > 0)
                {
                    printf("A : \t%d\n", upLetters[0]);
                }
                if(upLetters[1] > 0)
                {
                    printf("B : \t%d\n", upLetters[1]);
                }
                if(upLetters[2] > 0)
                {
                    printf("C : \t%d\n", upLetters[2]);
                }
                if(upLetters[3] > 0)
                {
                    printf("D : \t%d\n", upLetters[3]);
                }
                if(upLetters[4] > 0)
                {
                    printf("E : \t%d\n", upLetters[4]);
                }
                if(upLetters[5] > 0)
                {
                    printf("F : \t%d\n", upLetters[5]);
                }
                if(upLetters[6] > 0)
                {
                    printf("G : \t%d\n", upLetters[6]);
                }
                if(upLetters[7] > 0)
                {
                    printf("H : \t%d\n", upLetters[7]);
                }
                if(upLetters[8] > 0)
                {
                    printf("I : \t%d\n", upLetters[8]);
                }
                if(upLetters[9] > 0)
                {
                    printf("J : \t%d\n", upLetters[9]);
                }
                if(upLetters[10] > 0)
                {
                    printf("K : \t%d\n", upLetters[10]);
                }
                if(upLetters[11] > 0)
                {
                    printf("L : \t%d\n", upLetters[11]);
                }
                if(upLetters[12] > 0)
                {
                    printf("M : \t%d\n", upLetters[12]);
                }
                if(upLetters[13] > 0)
                {
                    printf("N : \t%d\n", upLetters[13]);
                }
                if(upLetters[14] > 0)
                {
                    printf("O : \t%d\n", upLetters[14]);
                }
                if(upLetters[15] > 0)
                {
                    printf("P : \t%d\n", upLetters[15]);
                }
                if(upLetters[16] > 0)
                {
                    printf("Q : \t%d\n", upLetters[16]);
                }
                if(upLetters[17] > 0)
                {
                    printf("R : \t%d\n", upLetters[17]);
                }
                if(upLetters[18] > 0)
                {
                    printf("S : \t%d\n", upLetters[18]);
                }
                if(upLetters[19] > 0)
                {
                    printf("T : \t%d\n", upLetters[19]);
                }
                if(upLetters[20] > 0)
                {
                    printf("U : \t%d\n", upLetters[20]);
                }
                if(upLetters[21] > 0)
                {
                    printf("V : \t%d\n", upLetters[21]);
                }
                if(upLetters[22] > 0)
                {
                    printf("W : \t%d\n", upLetters[22]);
                }
                if(upLetters[23] > 0)
                {
                    printf("X : \t%d\n", upLetters[23]);
                }
                if(upLetters[24] > 0)
                {
                    printf("Y : \t%d\n", upLetters[24]);
                }
                if(upLetters[25] > 0)
                {
                    printf("Z : \t%d\n", upLetters[25]);
                }

                if(loLetters[0] > 0)
                {
                    printf("a : \t%d\n", upLetters[0]);
                }
                if(loLetters[1] > 0)
                {
                    printf("b : \t%d\n", upLetters[1]);
                }
                if(loLetters[2] > 0)
                {
                    printf("c : \t%d\n", upLetters[2]);
                }
                if(loLetters[3] > 0)
                {
                    printf("d : \t%d\n", upLetters[3]);
                }
                if(loLetters[4] > 0)
                {
                    printf("e : \t%d\n", upLetters[4]);
                }
                if(loLetters[5] > 0)
                {
                    printf("f : \t%d\n", upLetters[5]);
                }
                if(loLetters[6] > 0)
                {
                    printf("g : \t%d\n", upLetters[6]);
                }
                if(loLetters[7] > 0)
                {
                    printf("h : \t%d\n", upLetters[7]);
                }
                if(loLetters[8] > 0)
                {
                    printf("i : \t%d\n", upLetters[8]);
                }
                if(loLetters[9] > 0)
                {
                    printf("j : \t%d\n", upLetters[9]);
                }
                if(loLetters[10] > 0)
                {
                    printf("k : \t%d\n", upLetters[10]);
                }
                if(loLetters[11] > 0)
                {
                    printf("l : \t%d\n", upLetters[11]);
                }           
                if(loLetters[12] > 0)
                {
                    printf("m : \t%d\n", upLetters[12]);
                }
                if(loLetters[13] > 0)
                {
                    printf("n : \t%d\n", upLetters[13]);
                }
                if(loLetters[14] > 0)
                {
                    printf("o: \t%d\n", upLetters[14]);
                }
                if(loLetters[15] > 0)
                {
                    printf("p : \t%d\n", upLetters[15]);
                }
                if(loLetters[16] > 0)
                {
                    printf("q : \t%d\n", upLetters[16]);
                }
                if(loLetters[17] > 0)
                {
                    printf("r : \t%d\n", upLetters[17]);
                }
                if(loLetters[18] > 0)
                {
                    printf("s : \t%d\n", upLetters[18]);
                }
                if(loLetters[19] > 0)
                {
                    printf("t : \t%d\n", upLetters[19]);
                }
                if(loLetters[20] > 0)
                {
                    printf("u : \t%d\n", upLetters[20]);
                }
                if(loLetters[21] > 0)
                {
                    printf("v : \t%d\n", upLetters[21]);
                }
                if(loLetters[22] > 0)
                {
                    printf("w : \t%d\n", upLetters[22]);
                }
                if(loLetters[23] > 0)
                {
                    printf("x : \t%d\n", upLetters[23]);
                }
                if(loLetters[24] > 0)
                {
                    printf("y : \t%d\n", upLetters[24]);
                }
                if(loLetters[25] > 0)
                {
                    printf("z : \t%d\n", upLetters[25]);
                }


             }
         }
```

Comment: First of all, you should be writing  a different function for each of the output requirements mentioned there. Take the input in main and pass it to different functions. That ought to make it simpler.

Comment: Is this C or C++? you seem to use `#include <string>` and `string word;`

Comment: I messed up there, I'm going to delete that string word, and I also am using different functions for each print requirements. This is C btw.

Comment: do a google search on for loops. never write down all indices of an array like that, it's programming 101, literally.

Comment: I couldn't because a loop wouldn't be able to change the index and the alphabet printed for each index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a bit of flexibility for analyzing the count by storing alphabet, number character counts, spaces and special counts in your `count` array. Separating your input processing and output into their own functions can also help keep things readable. For your `word` count, that depends heavily on how you define a **word** and how you count sequential whitespace in your code. In the simply case, the word count is simply `spaces + 1` in for example a sentence. But that will not do for files with long strings of whitespace separating columns.

the following show putting these principles in practice. The spaces are collected, but the number of words is left for your definition. The code process input from `stdin` if no arguments are given or expects an input filename as the first argument. Let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COUNTSZ 64
#define ALPHASZ 26
#define NOFFSET (ALPHASZ) * 2

void analizefile (char *fn, int *cnt);
void prnanalysis (int *cnt);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count[COUNTSZ] = {0};
    char *fn = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : NULL;

    analizefile (fn, count);

    prnanalysis (count);

    return 0;
}

void analizefile (char *fn, int *cnt)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int c, numbers, spaces, special;
    c = numbers = spaces = special = 0;

    if (fn) {
        if (!(fp = fopen (fn, "r"))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: file open failed '%s'.\n", __func__, fn);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
        fp = stdin;

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            cnt[c - 'A']++;
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            cnt[c - 'a' + ALPHASZ]++;
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            cnt[c - '0' + NOFFSET]++;
        else if ( c == ' ' )
            cnt[COUNTSZ - 2]++;
        else
            cnt[COUNTSZ - 1]++;
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);
}

void prnanalysis (int *cnt)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *set = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01123456789";

    printf ("\nThe frequency analysis of the input characters:\n\n");
    printf (" Spaces  : %d\n Special : %d\n\n", cnt[COUNTSZ - 2], cnt[COUNTSZ - 1]);

    printf ("Alphabet Characters:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ALPHASZ; i++)
        printf ("    %c    : %4d        %c    : %4d\n",
                set[i], cnt[i], set[i + ALPHASZ], cnt[i + ALPHASZ]);

    printf ("\nNumbers:\n");

    for (i = ALPHASZ * 2; i < COUNTSZ - 2; i++)
        printf ("    %c    : %d\n",  set[i], cnt[i]);

    printf ("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/charcount_case <~/doc/bash/ascii-chars.txt

The frequency analysis of the input characters:

 Spaces  : 1106
 Special : 318

Alphabet Characters:
    A    :    1        a    :   16
    B    :    1        b    :   13
    C    :    5        c    :   25
    D    :    5        d    :   15
    E    :    1        e    :   26
    F    :    1        f    :   10
    G    :    1        g    :    2
    H    :    5        h    :    7
    I    :    1        i    :    2
    J    :    1        j    :    1
    K    :    1        k    :    3
    L    :    1        l    :    6
    M    :    1        m    :    2
    N    :    1        n    :    8
    O    :    5        o    :    4
    P    :    1        p    :    3
    Q    :    1        q    :    2
    R    :    1        r    :    7
    S    :    1        s    :   14
    T    :    1        t    :   11
    U    :    1        u    :    4
    V    :    1        v    :    2
    W    :    1        w    :    1
    X    :    1        x    :  135
    Y    :    1        y    :    2
    Z    :    1        z    :    1

Numbers:
    0    : 400
    1    : 183
    1    : 89
    2    : 81
    3    : 81
    4    : 80
    5    : 80
    6    : 80
    7    : 31
    8    : 31
```